# Check if buttons are clicked in certain sequence JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I would like to make Javascript check if buttons are clicked in certain order (I working on the "Simon Game"). An order is an array of number, and every number corresponds to certain div (button). But something is wrong with my code, and it doesn't work.

The proper running code do this:

If I click right `div-button` and if I make a mistake it returns `false`, if all the sequence is clicked right return `true`.

```js
  function getRandArray() {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
      array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    }
    return array;
  }
  var array = getRandArray();
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.bigButton');
  function checkSound(level) {
    var counter = 0;
    var checkArr = array.slice(0, level - 1);
    console.log(checkArr);
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      elems[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if (this.dataset.sound === checkArr[counter]) {
          counter++;
          console.log('right');
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      })
    }
  }
  checkSound(5);
```

```css
.bigButton {
  height: 25px;
  width: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #464646;
  margin: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigButton" id="greenButton" data-sound="1">1
</div>
<div class="bigButton" id="redButton" data-sound="2">2
</div>
<div class="bigButton" id="yellowButton" data-sound="3">3
</div>
<div class="bigButton" id="blueButton" data-sound="4">4
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `===` by `==` in :

```
if (this.dataset.sound == checkArr[counter]) {
```

Since the `checkArr[counter]` is a number and `this.dataset.sound` is a string and triple equals `===` will compare the type also so the consition will never be reached.

Or you could also parse the string to integer using `parseInt()` like :

```
if (parseInt(this.dataset.sound) === checkArr[counter]) {
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function getRandArray() {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
      array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    }
    return array;
  }
  var array = getRandArray();
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.bigButton');
  function checkSound(level) {
    var counter = 0;
    var checkArr = array.slice(0, level - 1);
    console.log(checkArr);
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
      elems[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if (this.dataset.sound == checkArr[counter]) {
          counter++;
          console.log('right');
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      })
    }
  }
  checkSound(5);
```

```css
.bigButton {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #464646;
  margin: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigButton" id="greenButton" data-sound="1">1
</div>
<div class="bigButton" id="redButton" data-sound="2">2
</div>
<div class="bigButton" id="yellowButton" data-sound="3">3
</div>
<div class="bigButton" id="blueButton" data-sound="4">4
</div>
<br><br><br>
```

Comment: yes it helped)
as variant  add **"+"** before **this.dataset.sound**). Thanks. I didn't thought about it, thought it something worse